# How to specialize a generic enum in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I'm using the [antitypical/result](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) package to provide a generic Result type. This package defines Result as follows:

```
public enum Result<T, Error> {
     ...
}
```

Now, I only wish to return errors of type `NSError` in my code, so it would be nice if I didn't have to keep doing things this:

```
func myFunc() -> Result<String, NSError> { ... }
```

Instead, I want to create a derived StdResult type so that I can do this instead:

```
func myFunc() -> StdResult<String> { ... }
```

I've tried various things but I can't find a solution. This, for example, doesn't work:

```
typealias StdResult<T> = Result<T, NSError>
```

Is there a solution which will work?

Comment: will overloading do what you need? have `func myFunc() -> StdResult<String> { ... }` call `func myFunc() -> Result<String, NSError> { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we're pretty limited here.  Swift doesn't support generic typealias, so we can do this as a sort of hack with struct:

```
struct StdResult<T> {
    typealias Type = Test<T, NSError>
}

func myFunc() -> StdResult<String>.Type {

}
```

Does that fit what you were looking for closely enough?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there's no generic *typealias* support nor enumeration inheritance, but you could use `RawRepresentable` protocol. It's not as easy as if a generic typealias exists, but it may fit your needs.

#### RawRepresentable

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_RawRepresentable_Protocol/):

> A type that can be converted to an associated "raw" type, then converted back to produce an instance equivalent to the original.

```
public protocol RawRepresentable {
  typealias RawValue
  public init?(rawValue: Self.RawValue)
  public var rawValue: Self.RawValue { get }
}
```

---

That said, your *raw value* must be `Result<T, NSError>`:

```
enum StdResult<T>: RawRepresentable {

  var rawValue: Result<T, NSError> {
    switch self {
    case .Success(let value):
      return Result.Success(value)
    case .Failure(let error):
      return Result.Failure(error)
    }
  }
  
  init?(rawValue: Result<T, NSError>) {
    switch rawValue {
    case .Success(let value):
      self = .Success(value)
    case .Failure(let error):
      self = .Failure(error)
    }
  }

  case Success(T)
  case Failure(NSError)
}

func myFunc() -> StdResult<String> { }
```

**Note**: Properties and methods of original  `Result` enumeration are **only** accessible from  `rawValue` property, so, for example, if you want to compare your new `StdResult` with another, you **must** use `rawValue` property or reimplement these protocols yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could alias the specific Result type so you don't have to constantly do `func myThing() -> Result<String, NSError>`

e.g.

```
typealias StringResult = Result<String, NSError>

func myOtherThing() -> StringResult
```

It's more difficult for me to come up with a generic solution like

```
MyResult<String>
```

without understanding exactly what `Result` is doing.  I could take another crack at it if you post some of the internals.